# javascript inside asp.net not setting hidden field value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, geolocation

I am new to Asp.net. I am trying to get the latitude and longitude using GeoLocation and trying to set the values to the hidden fields on PageLoad.

Problem is the value of the Hidden Fields always remains empty. But please see the alert statement in the JavaScript call, the alert correctly displays both latitude and longitude value. How can I populate the hidden fields in the C#  code so I can send these values as email when Page Loads. Please help

aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script>
       window.onload = getLocation();
       var x = document.getElementById("demo");
       function getLocation() {
           if (navigator.geolocation) {
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
           }
           else { x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }
       }
        function showPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('<%=Latitide.ClientID%>').value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById('<%=Longitude.ClientID%>').value = position.coords.longitude;
           alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
               "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);

       }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <br />
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Latitide" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" />
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Longitude" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Write("Latitude " + Latitide.Value + "-Longitude" + Request.Form["Longitude"]);
    }


}
```

Comment: you hard coded the ID's in the view...so use same values for `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side code (Page_Load) executes when the page is first requested, at which point those values are empty, as set within ASPX markup (towards the bottom of that file).

When that file is then served to the browser, it executes the JavaScript code that you have (onload), at which point values of those hidden fields are set (but you still won't see them within page-source as such). If you javascript-alert this:

`document.getElementById('<%=Longitude.ClientID%>').value`

... I think you'll see what you expect.

I'd need to know more about the intention of that webpage to provide more guidance.

Comment: Hi Hari, you are right when I say document.getElementById('<%=Longitude.ClientID%>').value in the alert I am able to see the values. My intent is I want to show get the latitiude and longitude in the C# code on Page Load so I can send these values using an email. Is it possible to do it?Is there a way to delay to wait till I get the values

Comment: You need to add ASP.NET button control, then you need to have associated server-side OnClick event, then move that code from Page_Load there. There are many guides on how to do this; here's one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuFuq-b_dHo . Keywords to google: "asp.net button tutorial"